# Linked Server on Express and Upgrading to SQL Server 2014 Standard

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

We have a server running SQL Server 2014 Express, and we want to upgrade to Standard edition. We have a linked server running on Express edition. Can we upgrade to Standard edition and the linked server will carry across?

We tried recreating the linked server with the exact same values just a different name, but the new linked servers all fail with 'incorrect user/password' errors.

I don't know how the current linked server connects as the tns file has no info within it.

Please help

TIA

Comment: Did you script the linked server as a `Create To` and re-create it that way? or did you re-create the linked server by memory?

Comment: I scripted it out, and then also changed the password to the one required before executing

Comment: Will the linked server and databases work automatically when the upgrade finishes ? Or is there something that has to be done ? I did a backup just in case